# What kind of speaker can be used with an LM386?

Tags: speakers, lm386

I am trying to use an [LM386](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) to drive some speakers. I have both a 4Ω 4W speaker and 8Ω 1.5W speaker. Would I have to build a different circuit for each of these and would the LM386 be able to drive both speakers in parallel at once?

Using the formula P=R(I^2), I would get that the 4W speaker needs 1A and the 1.5W speaker needs 0.43A, so can the LM386 handle 1.5A? Or is my logic here wrong?

Comment: LM386 doesn't drive 4 ohms very well. It's a bit better driving 8 ohms but it's too low power to get the best out of either speaker. If you're stuck with it, use the 8 ohm spkr.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, could you explain why it wouldn't? Is the resistance of the speaker too low (and therefore a higher current)?

Comment: Read the datasheet. Note the power ratings into 4 and 8 ohm loads on the graphs. Or try it and see for yourself.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Okay, I see what you are saying. Could a parallel two of these ICs, or do they work like transistors where paralleling them would force one of them to take all the load?

Comment: You could *try* but it would be much simpler to use a more suitable amplifier. There are hundreds, I'm not going to suggest one.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the 8Ω 1.5W if the only option is to drive the speaker directly because that chip is low power.